# Is storing plain password in session acceptable when using it do decrypt with AES?

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes

I wrote a web app in PHP, which is processing some secret data, placed in one database table. All fields in this table (excluding id and date of creation) are encrypted with AES, so nobody who has got access to this database can read it.

I encrypt that data with user password. There's no plain password anywhere in database, just the SHA1 sum, so I can verify it. However, I need plain password to decrypt user data when he's logged in, so I store this value in session.

Is it OK for this purpose? If not, what are the good patterns to deal with this case?

Comment: Once encrypted you can't decrypt it obviously.

Comment: If you're on a shared host, you should be careful with sessions. Another user on the same server may be able to read your session data and view passwords

Comment: @Jonathon, I know. Application is deployed on shared server, but has its own host.

Comment: Maybe you could generate an encryption key from the inputted password, that way you aren't storing plaintext passwords. However, what if a user changes his/her password? To me it seems like you're probably overcomplicating things

Comment: session is invariably some lightly serialized text on the drive. That means you'd be storing your users' password in trivially accessible/readable/stealable fashion, meaning your security is essentially non-existent. You might as well **NOT** encrypt their data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I encrypt that data with user password

If they change their password you then have to re-encrypt everything. Look into something more static for the key.

> so I store this value in session.

The session should not store this type of information as anyone else with a website on the box (or any other way to access the box) may be able to read it. If your box uses something similar to suPHP or phpSuExec (ask your host) you could place this data in a directory that only your account can access. You could even store it back in the database (encrypted of course).

> what are the good patterns to deal with this case?

If security is important to you, go dedicated. If you're unable to do that then at least be on a server that uses suPHP or phpSuExec or the like so that your web server processes run under a unique user so that any data related to the encryption key can be secured.

Answer (score 0):

`so nobody who has got access to this database can read it`.

By storing your password in the session, you will have a lot of session files in your `/tmp` directory (or wherever they are stored...) containing users passwords.

Not only does access to your server invalidate your first statement (when you have access to the server, you have direct access to lots of passwords), but someone with server access - even a valid server admin like yourself - can see passwords he or she should never be able to see.

So no, this is not OK.

A possible solution to your problem would be to use an encryption key for the user information that is stored on a different server so that access to the database / database server alone is not enough. However, this is just a thought, you might get a better answer to that question on for example https://security.stackexchange.com/